# Conditionally appending a detached element

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to append a detached `span` based on certain condition like following.

```js
const arrow = d3
    .create('span')
    .classed('arrow', true)
    .text('\u2192');

  //d3.select('body').append(()=>arrow.node());        

  const threshold = 16;

  d3.selectAll('div')
    .each(function(d, i) {
        const len = this.textContent.length;
        //console.log(len);

        d3.select(this)
            .append(function() {
                const node = arrow.node();
                const finalVal = (len <= threshold) ? node : null;
                return finalVal;

            })
    })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <div class='text1'>this is line one</div>
    <div class='text2'>this is line two</div>
    <div class='text3'>this is line three</div>
    <div class='text4'>this is line four</div>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

But unfortunately, I see this error `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.` in the browser console and also, I expect the `span` to be appended to the first div as well.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On top of what the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73638131/5768908) said (+1), your problem here is that you believe that you just need to create the detached element **once**, and then you can append it again and again.

However, if you look at the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) regarding `appendChild` (which D3 uses internally), you'll see:

> If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position — there is no requirement to remove the node from its parent node before appending it to some other node. This means that **a node can't be in two points of the document simultaneously**. (the emphasis here is mine).

The solution here is creating the detached element inside the `each` loop:

```js
   

const threshold = 16;

d3.selectAll('div')
  .each(function(d, i) {
    const len = this.textContent.length;
    if (len <= threshold) {
      const arrow = d3
        .create('span')
        .classed('arrow', true)
        .text('\u2192');
      d3.select(this)
        .append(() => arrow.node())
    }
  })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class='text1'>this is line one</div>
  <div class='text2'>this is line two</div>
  <div class='text3'>this is line three</div>
  <div class='text4'>this is line four</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>

</html>
```

But using `d3.create` in this case is a bit pointless, because you can simply append the element you want the regular way. If you want to keep using `d3.create`, you can create the detached element once and append clones of it:

```
d3.select(this).append(() => arrow.node().cloneNode(true))
```

Here's the demo:

```js
const arrow = d3
  .create('span')
  .classed('arrow', true)
  .text('\u2192');

const threshold = 16;

d3.selectAll('div')
  .each(function(d, i) {
    const len = this.textContent.length;
    if (len <= threshold) {
      d3.select(this)
        .append(() => arrow.node().cloneNode(true))
    }
  })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class='text1'>this is line one</div>
  <div class='text2'>this is line two</div>
  <div class='text3'>this is line three</div>
  <div class='text4'>this is line four</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes that was exactly my thinking behind that. This is simply awesome !!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
  d3.selectAll('div')
    .each(function(d, i) {
        (this.textContent.length <= threshold) && d3.select(this)
            .append(function() {
                return arrow.node();
            })
    })
```

Explaination :

In your code, you were trying to append `null` hence you cought up with errors.
Here I'm checking the condition first and then appending it.

Hope this helps you!